# How to design a list with image and text in react js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hello friends i am new in react js. i want to display a list with image and text using html and css usnig bootstrap. like this [image: sample image] that list contain songs images  and also contain option for download and like after user click on that three dots.
Thanks in advance :)

using this code i am able to display the image with text and heart icon now the three dot remain on which i want to open the option like and download how to do that ? please help

on three dot click open list [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Rounded Corners</h2>
  <p>The .rounded class adds rounded corners to an image:</p>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="cinqueterre.jpg" class="rounded img-fluid" alt="Cinque Terre" height="150px" width="150px">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <h5> Test test </h5>
     <p> test demo add here </p>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-5 jusfity-content-end">
     <span> 12.35 PM</span>
     <span class="fa fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </span>
   <span class="fa fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </span>

   </div>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

the above code tried on w3school site

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: tried with using ul tag but not able to align the image and text in one row so now i am trying with div in render function passing the function name which contain a div with same design row

Comment: Nice, it would be easy for us to help you if we can see your code. So that we don't have to rewrite/implement everything.

Comment: @bertdida i have added the code please check now i want display the three dots after click on three dots open the like and comment options

Comment: You don't seem to be using react in the sample code you have shared. Are you planning to add react or just plain javascript?

Comment: first i am trying to catch the design as per requirement.in react render i am just using the code from container div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is your new friend.

I did something pretty quick, but you should be using a lot `display: flex`, different `justify-content` and `align-items` values. And play around, a lot.

The images I used are screenshots, they are a bit ugly. But you should use `border-radius` and `object-fit: contain`

https://jsfiddle.net/MarkBurnsRed/h7g04ns2/110/

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply. i want to open list on three dot click. please check once